# How to go directly to a particular section of a html page on page load?

Tags: html, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have implemented a bootstrap wizard on my page but on page load I have to go to second tab or section of the wizard so what should I do? How do I pass the second tab or section id to the URL so that it directly gets me to the section of the page?

Comment: Are you using jQuery as well?

Comment: Yes I am using jquery as well

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show'); // Select tab by name
$('#myTab a:first').tab('show'); // Select first tab
$('#myTab a:last').tab('show'); // Select last tab
$('#myTab li:eq(2) a').tab('show'); // Select third tab (0-indexed)
```

Comment: if this answered your question, dont forget to mark it checked ;)

Answer (score 1):

Consider you have following structure of the tab:

```
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Consider this tab is placed in the URL `/profile/me`. Now you can use the following URLs to switch between tabs on page load like: `/profile/me#home`, `/profile/me#profile` or `/profile/me#messages`. Then you will need the following Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Register an event
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        // Set the hash with the active tab on tab change
        location.href = $(e.target).attr("href")
    });

    // You will get like "", "#profile", "#messages"
    var tabName = location.hash;
    // remove # from the name
    tabName = tabName.substring(1);

    if (tabName) {
        $("#tablist a[href='#" + tabName + "']").tab('show');
    }
});
```

### Using AngularJS routing without HTML5 mode

You need to alter your code a bit if you are using AngularJS routing with non HTML5 mode since the URL will already have `#`